# android studio do not add missing imports

Tags: android-studio

I'm posting this question to ask some help with an android studio's very annoying behavior : sometimes happen that in my code there are some missing imports and when I click on run button on the "message" tab all the errors appears, but when I click on the error to open the related file, android studio automatically add the missing imports.

What I want to know is if there is a way to make those imports to be added without the need of opening file, it is very annoying when you have errors on a lot of files. I tryied with the options under "Code" menu, but it seem it don't work. Does anyone found the same problem?

this is my "Auto import" setting's section

[image]
thank you

Comment: How exactly do you end up with many files that have missing imports?

Comment: i still did not ended up

Comment: My question is: what do you do exactly that leads to having many files with missing import statements? I never encounter such situations in my own work.

Comment: I work with SMP (Sybase Mobile Platform). It works using a set of source files generated server side. When there is the need to change this package I need to delete the old package e replace it. This opeations causes imports to be broken where the classes in sup package are used. This is how I end up with missing imports